# When will Object.assign return false

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

The following code is from the index.js file in the graphql-yoga package.

Can someone explain to me under what scenario "Object.assign" would return false and trigger the anonymous function being assigned to the variable instead?

```
"use strict";
var __assign = (this && this.__assign) || function () {
    __assign = Object.assign || function(t) {
        for (var s, i = 1, n = arguments.length; i < n; i++) {
            s = arguments[i];
            for (var p in s) if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(s, p))
                t[p] = s[p];
        }
        return t;
    };
    return __assign.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

It seems to me that Object.assign will always return true as "assign" is a built in method of Object.

```
var test  = Object.assign;
if(test) console.log("it is true")
```

the result is "it is true" being printed to the console as expected

Comment: `Object.assign` would be _falsy_ if it were not defined. For example, in IE9. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object.assign is not available in ES5, it's introduced in ES6. So I assume the above code is written that way to be compatible with ES5.

Answer (score 1):

The only case would be if `Object.assign` didn't exist - in an ES5 environment for instance. In that case, because you wouldn't be attempting to *call* `undefined`, it wouldn't result in an error and would instead pass to the next function (because `undefined` is falsy).

Comment: nice complete explanation. Would have chosen this answer if I saw it first. Still learning how to use this site